# Data manipulations

Tags: r

I have a csv file with data in the following format:

```
2014-01-05 23:05:42 Nicole  2014-01-05 22:41:26     
2014-01-06 13:02:58 Albert  2014-01-06 11:58:14
2014-01-08 03:04:49 Nicole  2014-01-08 02:49:58
2014-01-08 03:04:49 Nicole  2014-01-08 02:49:58
2014-01-08 08:26:41 Marlen  2014-01-08 05:45:08
```

Where the first date is the updated date, and second one is the created time.
Basically, can I count the amount of time passed between the dates and then the media for each person?

Comment: Please show us your desired output too.

Comment: Name -  Average value of the difference between dates

Comment: For example for Nicole is 24, 15, 15 min
So I want the output data look like Nicole - 18

Comment: Try something like `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, mean(difftime(V1, V3, units = "mins")), by = V2]` if `V1`, `V2` and `V3` are your column names columns while both `V1` and `V3` are of class `POSIXct`

Comment: Is there a way to change column class to POSIXct?

Comment: Something like ```setDT(df)[, `:=`(V1 = as.POSIXct(V1), V3 = as.POSIXct(V3))]``` in your example. See my answer.

Comment: That's how it looks now:
`library(data.table) 
setDT(audit_status)[?, mean(difftime((updated_time = as.POSIXct(updated_time), created_time = as.POSIXct(created_time)), units = "min")), by = agent]` What should be on the place of ?

Comment: You don't need to place nothing there. Just remove that `?` out of there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation using `data.table`. Here we first convert to `POSIXct` class and then calculate the mean difference in minutes per name. You can add `round` if you like.

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df)[, `:=`(V1 = as.POSIXct(V1), V3 = as.POSIXct(V3))]
df[, mean(difftime(V1, V3, units = "mins")), by = V2]
#        V2             V1
# 1: Nicole  17.98889 mins
# 2: Albert  64.73333 mins
# 3: Marlen 161.55000 mins
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("2014-01-05 23:05:42", 
"2014-01-06 13:02:58", "2014-01-08 03:04:49", "2014-01-08 08:26:41"
), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Albert", 
"Marlen", "Nicole"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("2014-01-05 22:41:26", "2014-01-06 11:58:14", 
"2014-01-08 02:49:58", "2014-01-08 05:45:08"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

---

See [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for some more information regarding `data.table`

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now that works. Last question, how can I arrange V2 in the table like 1-2-3?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. you can change `by` to `keyby` while running the second line. Or you could save the result in a new object and add a row index. Something like `res <- df[, mean(difftime(V1, V3, units = "mins")), keyby = V2]` and then `res[, indx := .I]`. Then check out `res`

Comment: Sorry, I meant how can I sort by V2 value. For example `17.9-64.73-161.55 `

Comment: Add `order` at the end, something like `ddf[, .(Mean = mean(difftime(V1, V3, units = "mins"))), by = V2][order(Mean)]`

Answer (score 1):

A similar option using `dplyr` (data from @DavidArenburg's post).  We group by 'V2', convert the columns 'V1', 'V3' to `POSIXct` class using `mutate_each`, and `summarise` to get the `mean` of difference in time between 'V1 and 'V3'.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(V2) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(as.POSIXct(.)), V1, V3) %>% 
  summarise(DiffMean = mean(difftime(V1, V3, units="mins")))

#      V2       DiffMean
#  (fctr)         (dfft)
#1 Albert  64.73333 mins
#2 Marlen 161.55000 mins
#3 Nicole  17.98889 mins
```